# Insert JSON template from file into mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a template of nested json in a text a file.

The template looks like

```
$ cat file.txt
{ "sensor" : {
"type":  "unknown",
"notifications": "off"
"timeout": "0"
"featureset": {
  "features":  [ 
  {
  "name": "Temp",
  "enabled": "No",
  },
  {
  "name": "Humidity",
  "enabled": "No",
  } ] }
 }
}
```

I would like, upon condition, to read the template into a python variable, then change some fields if I need to (i.e `"notifications": "on"`). Then save it into mongodb database.

My curent code looks like:

```
dbclient = MongoClient()
db = dbclient.sensors

def main():
    with open ("file.txt", 'r') as template:
    data = template.read()
    print ('data: %s' % data)
    dbdata = db.testdata
    post_id = dbdata.insert_one(bson.BSON.encode(data.strip("\r\n")))
    print ('Inserted post id %s ' % post_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this doesn't work. I get `TypeError: encoder expected a mapping type but got: ...`

How do I convert this string read from text file into a mongodb suitable format?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you provide correct content of the `file.txt`? If it is, you file is not valid MongoDB ducument and is not valid JSON.

Comment: Changed it, still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your file valid JSON data. This means no terminal commas for last items in JSON arrays or last pairs in JSON Objects.

```
{
    "sensor": {
        "type": "unknown",
        "notifications": "off",
        "timeout": "0",
        "featureset": {
            "features": [
                {
                    "name": "Temp",
                    "enabled": "No"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Humidity",
                    "enabled": "No"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Next note the following information in the docs about `BSON.encode` and `pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one`

[`bson.BSON.encode`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.0/bson/__init__.py#L996) must be passed a `document` among other parameters.
A document can be any mapping type (like :class:`dict`).

[`pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.0/pymongo/collection.py#L637) should be passed an instance of `dict`, `bson.son.SON`, `bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument`, or a type that inherits from `collections.MutableMapping`.

**Knowing that** a mutable map can be passed, we can deserialize our JSON template to it's Python representation and have it inserted directly.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

dbclient = MongoClient()
db = dbclient.sensors

def main():
    with open('fakedata/sensor.json') as template:
        template_dct = json.load(template)

    result = db.test.insert_one(template_dct)
    print('Inserted post id %s ' % result.inserted_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```